# Crashing Application with self.tableview reloadData

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, crash

I am doing a simple app in XCode with two TableViewControllers, a click on the first takes you to the second where you put your name, however i am getting a crash at the line where says: "self.tableView reloadData", how could I fix this problem?
I got to the main and says Thread 1:signal  SIGABRT 
  argv  char ** 0xbfffed90  0xbfffed90
*argv   char *  "/Users/maciosdeveloping/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/20050884-B77A-47FC-98B6-500B5D44D9FB/EjemploModal.app/EjemploModal"    0xbfffef10
**argv  char    '/' '/'
argc    int 1   1

```
NSMutableArray *alumnos;

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"transicion"]){
    UINavigationController *navigationController=segue.destinationViewController;
    MODetalleViewController *moDetalleViewController =[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
    moDetalleViewController.delegate=self;
}
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
alumnos=[NSMutableArray array];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload{
[self viewDidUnload];
alumnos=nil;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [alumnos count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Alumno";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text=[alumnos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

#pragma mark Protocolo de detalle

-(void)AlumnoDetallesViewControllerDelegateDidCancel:(MODetalleViewController *)controller{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)AlumnoDetallesViewControllerDelegateDidSave:(MODetalleViewController *)controller{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[alumnos addObject:controller.nombre.text];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Can you please post log of the crash.

Comment: I have a feeling that "`self.tableView`" isn't correctly hooked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidUnload{
[self viewDidUnload];
alumnos=nil;
}
```

This will go into an infinite loop. Correct `[super viewDidUnload]`

Put the dismiss code at the end of the method and try!

```
-(void)AlumnoDetallesViewControllerDelegateDidSave:(MODetalleViewController *)controller{

[alumnos addObject:controller.nombre.text];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: yeah I got wrong with that. However that doesn´t solve the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you please post log of the crash?

Comment: You are dismissing the viewController and accessing it's property! When you dismiss a ViewController, then it calls viewDidUnload: and you are unable to access local variables. So dismiss the viewController at the end! Did this help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be caused by accessing a member of a controller you are at the same time dismissing:

```
-(void)AlumnoDetallesViewControllerDelegateDidSave:(MODetalleViewController *)controller{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   [alumnos addObject:controller.nombre.text];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Try with:

```
[alumnos addObject:[controller.nombre.text copy]];
```

This will add a copy of the text you entered in the detail controller view to your data source.

A better advice would be making your data source a part of the model (as in Model-View-Controlelr) of your app. So, your detail view controller would update the app model when the user enters new detail info; the main view controller can access the new data from the model instead of from the detail controller.

(If you are not using ARC, this will produce a memory leak, btw, and you should add `autorelease`)